# C++ copy constructor using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, copy-constructor

Can anyone explain the meaning of `*p=*q` in this C++ code? Is this a copy constructor concept?

```
class A{
  //any code
}

int main(){
  A *p=new A();
  A *q=new A();
  *p=*q;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're diving in far too deep. Be sure to understand the basics first. The situation is just like in `int a;` `int *p = &a, *q = &a;` `*p = *q;`

Comment: @KerrekSB But in the OP's code `new A()` & `new A()` produce distinct instances, whereas your analogy uses a sole `int a` instance.  I think a better parallel would be: **`int a1 = 5, a2 = 10;` `int *p = &a1;` `int *q = &a2;` `*p = *q;`**

Comment: For any pointer `tp` that is of type `T*`, the expression `*tp` will dereference that pointer, evaluating to a value of type `T`, that is pointed to by `tp`.  So, you can read that as `the value pointed to by "p" = the value pointed to by "q";`

Answer (score 13):

> Is this a copy constructor concept?

No, what you are referring to is a copy assignment concept. Consider this:

```
int* p = new int{9};
int* q = new int{10};
*p = *q;
```

As you can see above, only the value of the variable `q` which is pointed to is copied. This is the equivalent of the copy assignment for objects. If you were to do this:

```
p = q;
```

Then this would not be a copy assignment, because both `int`'s point to the same address and value, meaning any change to `p` or `q` would be reflected on the other variable. 
To give a more concrete and validated example, here is some code:

```
int main() 
{
    int* p = new int{9};
    int* q = new int{10};
    *p = *q;
    //p = 10, q = 10
    *p = 11;
    //p = 11, q = 10
    delete p;
    delete q;
}
```

And here is a supplementary counter-example

```
int main() 
{
    int* p = new int{9};
    int* q = new int{10};
    p = q;
    //p = 10, q = 10
    *p = 11;
    //p = 11, q = 11
    delete p;
    //delete q; Not needed because p and q point to same int
}
```

As you can see, the changes are reflected on both variables for `p=q`

**Side Note**
You mentioned copy-construction, but you were unclear about the concept. Here is what copy-construction would have looked like:

```
int* p = new int{9};
int* q = new int{*p}; //q=9
```

Copy construction differs from copy assignment in the sense that with copy construction, the variable doesn't already have a value, and for an object, the constructor has yet to be called. Mixing up the 2 terms is common, but the fundamental differences make the two concepts, well, different.

Comment: You forgot semicolons before the end of both `main`s

Answer (score 10):

It looks like, you're unclear about the copy constructor and copy assignment. Let's first have a look at both concepts individually, and then I'll come to your question. The answer is a little long, so be patient :)

**[Copy Constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor_(C%2B%2B))**

Here, I'm not going to explain how to write a copy constructor, but when the copy constructor is called and when it's not. (If you want to know, how to write a copy constructor, see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor))

A copy constructor is a special constructor for creating a new object as a copy of an existing object. (It is called whenever there's a need for making a copy of an existing object)

These are the scenarios when the copy constructor will be called to make the copy of an existing object:

---

- **Initializing an object with some previously created object**:

  ```
  SomeClass obj;
  // ...
  SomeClass anotherObj = obj; // here copy constructor will be called.
  ```

  See, `SomeClass obj;` statement is simply creating an object (here, [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) will be called to create the object). The second statement `SomeClass anotherObj = obj;` is instantiating an object, initialized with the values of `obj` (an existing object), so copy constructor will be called here. You can also initialize an object with an existing object this way: `SomeClass anotherObj(obj);` (This statement is equivalent to `SomeClass anotherObj = obj;`)

  **Except**:
  If you initialize with some *rvalue expression*. e.g.

  ```
  SomeClass someObject = aObject + anotherObject;
  ```

  In this case, **move constructor** will be called. See, [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics)

---

- **Passing an object by value to some function** (see [Passing arguments by value](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/72-passing-arguments-by-value/)):

  See, the following code snippet, here the function `doSomething` is accepting an object as parameter by value:

  ```
  void doSomething(SomeClass someObject)
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```

  There are some cases, when there will be a need to make the copy of the passed argument in the parameter object `someObject`, I've listed when there will be a need to make the copy and when there'll not be a need.

  Have a look at the following code snippet:

  ```
  SomeClass someObject;
  // ...
  doSomething(someObject); // here copy constructor will be called.
  ```

  The statement `SomeClass someObject;` is just instantiating `someObject` by calling the [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).

  The second statement `doSomething(someObject);` is calling the function `doSomething` previously shown, by passing `someObject` as argument. This is the case, when there's a need to make a copy of `someObject` to pass to the function.

  **Except**:
  Similiary, If we call `doSomething` with some *rvalue expression*, it will call *move constructor* instead of *copy constructor*.

---

- **Returning an object from a function by value**:

  Let's have a look at the following definition of `doSomething`

  ```
  SomeClass doSomehing()
  {
      SomeClass someObject;
      // ...
      return someObject;
  }
  ```

  In the above function `doSomething`, an object of `SomeClass` is being created and after doing some task, the object is being returned by the function, in this case, a copy of the `someObject` will be created and returned.

  **Except**:
  Similiary, If `doSomething` returns some *rvalue expression*, it will call *move constructor* instead of *copy constructor*.

---

**[Copy Assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B))**

Copy Assignment is usually confused with the copy construction, let's have a look at how it is different than the copy construction:

```
SomeClass someObject;
// ...
SomeClass anotherObject;
// ...
anotherObject = someObject; // here copy assignment operator will be called.
```

The first two statements are just creating `someObject` and `anotherObject`, you see, the third statement is actually calling the copy assignment operator and **not** the copy constructor.

Constructors are only called when some new object is being created. And in the case of `anotherObject = someObject;`, both the objects are already created, so there won't be any call to the copy constructor. Instead a copy assignment operator will be called (to see, how to overload a copy assignment operator, see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment))

---

Now, let's have a look at your code snippet:

> ```
> A *p=new A();
> A *q=new A();
> *p=*q;
> ```

In the first statement `A *p=new A();`, default constructor will be called to create an object (in this case, new object will be created on heap) and `p` will be initialized with the address of the newly created object (as `p` is a [pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/))

Similar is the case with second statement `A *q=new A();` (It is creating another object and `q` will be initialized with newly created object)

Now, the third statement: `*p = *q;` (here `*` is [Dereference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator))

To understand, what the third statement is doing, let's have a look at some pointers and de-referencing them to get the actual object, which they're pointing to.

```
int someVariable = 5;
int *somePointer = &someVariable;
// ...
*somePointer = 7;
```

Let's try to understand the above code snippet: `someVariable` is created and initialized with a value of `5`, then `somePointer` is created and initialized with the address of `someVariable`.

Now, the last statement `*somePointer = 7;`, it is actually de-referencing the `somePointer` and by de-referencing, it'll get the the variable which it is pointing to. (so it will get `someVariable`) and then it is assigning `7` to it. So after this statement, `someVariable`'s value will become `7`

Let's have another example:

```
int* somePointer = new int;
int* anotherPointer = new int;
// ...
*somePointer = 5;
*anotherPointer = 7;
// ...
*somePointer = *anotherPointer;
```

First, `somePointer` will be created and initialized with the address of dynamically allocated `int` variable (will be allocated in heap, see [Dynamic Allocation in c++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)), similarly, `anotherPointer` will be initialized with the address of another dynamically allocated variable.

Then, it is assigning `5` to the first variable (which is being pointed by `somePointer`) and `7` to the second variable (which is being pointed by `anotherPointer`)

Now, the last statement will be of your interest, `*somePointer = *anotherPointer;`, in this statement `*somePointer` is de-referencing and getting the first variable (whose value was `5`) and `*anotherPointer` is de-referencing and getting the second variable (whose value is `7`), and it is assigning the second variable to the first variable, resulting in changing the first variable's value to `7`.

Now, let's have a look at your `*p=*q;` statement, (`p` was pointing to the first object of `A`, and `q` was pointing to the second object of `A`, both dynamically allocated), `*p` will dereference `p` and get the first object, `*q` will dereference `q` and get the second object, and then the second object will be copied in the first object, and if you see, no new object is being created in `*p=*q;`, and only the value of second object is being created in the first object, so **copy assignment operator** will be called here and no the copy constructor.

**Another thing**

You should de-allocate the dynamically allocated memory which you borrowed using `new` operator:

```
delete p;
delete q;
```

You should add these two lines at the end of your program, so to avoid [Memory Leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the comments, one need to understand the basics first:

- With `A *p=new A();` one gets a pointer to a memory region on the heap in which an object of type `A` is constructed.
- With `*p` one dereferences the pointer, i.e. one retrieves the object.
- Now `*p = *q` uses the (possibly implicitly declared) assignment operator of class `A` in order to give `*p` -- the object pointed to by `p` -- the value of `*q`. This operation could equivalently be written as `p->operator=(*q)`.

The last step, the assignment, is identical to what you would obtain with objects instead of pointers (which is usually a better way to go in C++ and often called RAII):

```
A r;
A s;
r=s;
```